# How to use satellite maps in gmap 3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, ggmap, jquery-gmap3

I'm use gmap 3 in my website, but i want satellite map

here's my gmap 3 activation..

```
 $('.map') 
  .gmap3({
    center:[37.7638886, -122.4563572],
    zoom:14,
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeId: "shadeOfGrey", // to select it directly
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, "shadeOfGrey"]
      }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the value of `satellite` as the `mapTypeId` field in your `MapOptions` object:

```
$('.map') 
  .gmap3({
    center:[37.7638886, -122.4563572],
    zoom:14,
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeId: "satellite"
  })
```

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#BasicMapTypes)

Answer (score -1):

its work for me

```
    // satellite map active
     $('.map_se') 
      .gmap3({
        center:[40.748817, -73.985428],
        zoom:3,
        scrollwheel: false,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
      })
      .marker([
        {address:"46000, Canada", icon: "assets/img/map-icon.png"}
    ])
```